# iOS 16+ visible value returns false incorrectly for UI elements

Tags: flutter, automation, appium, ios16, appium-inspector

I am trying to inspect the Flutter app in SauceLabs but always getting a `visible` flag as false for a few elements even though it is visible. Due to this, all the automation scripts are stopped.

**Note: This is happening only in iOS 16+ OS.(working fine below iOS 16 OS and Android too)**

```
Appium version: 2.0.0
WebDriverAgent version: 8.5.1
iOS: 16.0
Flutter SDK: 3.7.10 (and also tried with the latest 3.16.2)
```

It looks like a similar issue was reported here bug with no solution: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/18113

Any suggestions would be constructive to solve this issue.

[image]